# Crash-репорты в android

Tags: android, исключения

Здравствуйте, меня "забанили в google" ( не нашел ответа на свой вопрос).

Встала задача, на приложении, собирать crash-репорты.

Firebase,flurry, fabric  как решения не устраивают руководство.

Какие еще есть варианты?

P.S. Предлагают писать свой сервер и посылать туда все сообщения о падениях, но очень хотелось бы избежать возни с сервером.

Comment: А чем их тот же firebase не устравиает? Вроде краши с аналитикой полностью бесплатны и подключаются, реально, в 2 строки вместе. Ещё HockeyApp есть.

Comment: Например, ACRA.

Comment: firebase, fabric,flurry - их отталкивает из-за страха за конфеденциальные данные. Типа нам их нельзя светит. И меня склонят писать сервак и собственную отправку крашей - но я не думаю что это будет лучше готовых решений

Comment: Немного не понятно какие конфиденциальные данные могут попасть в стек трейс?

Comment: Я им об этом говорил - но к сожалению решающего слова в проекте  у меня нету. Поэтому приходится искать варианты как выполнить задачу на их условиях.

Comment: @jangorussia, в таком случае ACRA вам подойдёт - просто пишете php скрипт строк на 50 который будет инфу в БД складывать. Работы часа на 2. Если, конечно, не нужны всякие красивые отображения как в сторонних решениях. Тогда да - долго и нужно пилить фронтэнд)

Comment: У ACRA есть нарядный [фронтэнд](https://github.com/ACRA/acralyzer). Поднимается все это дело за десяток кликов.

Comment: https://raygun.com/docs